# Redundancy: LVM+mdadm or LVM internal RAID

Tags: linux, software-raid, lvm, mdadm

The task is to create LVM storage for virtual machine images. So LVM will be used in any case.

There are two ways LVM providing redundancy:

1. block mirroring

   ```
   lvcreate -m 1 --mirrorlog mirrored -n logical_volume -L 50G vg0
   ```
2. internal RAID mechanism

   ```
   lvcreate --type=raid1 -n logical_volume -L 50G vg0
   ```

Second way should provide reading performance boost.

As alternative we can create raid1 with mdadm and use Linux Soft Raid device as physical volume for LVM.

Which way is better and why?